# cannot query data from linked server

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SANDBOX" does not contain the table ""abc_-03/11/2021"."Admin Access - View Only (BI - Web Services)"."xyz_SUBSCRIPTIONS"". The table either does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that table in sql server.

However there are some tables that I can query and get the data from this linked server. It is very confusing and I can't find a way out to complete the task.

Any suggestions that can help rectify the issue ?

Comment: Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70109784/edit) your question to include the full text of the actual error message? I'm only guessing, but perhaps the `"` characters could be a problem.

Comment: edited it , don't want to have privacy related issues !